# What happens to this energy of the capacitor?

Tags: energy, electrostatics, capacitance, dielectric

Let's say you have a charged, isolated parallel plate capacitor with a certain voltage. My book says that if you insert a dielectric, the voltage drops. However, that would require the energy between the plates to go down. What is this energy converted to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The energy is used to polarize the dielectric, i.e.: Moving charges inside the dielectric.

Comment: what happens if the dielectric is then pulled out  ?